# Sendkeys.send Ignoring messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

Anytime a message box or a custom box is suppose to be displayed in the program is bypassed
when the sendkeys command is sent. For example:

```
SendKeys.Send("{F7}");
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = 
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel the transacation", 
        "Cancel Trans", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //clear the trans
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        //close con goes back 
    }
}
```

If i hit <kbd>f7</kbd> on my keyboard I actually see this and can choose

If I use the sendkeys command it doesn't display this and automatically hits yes
has anyone ran into this i have tried the sendkeys.sendwait command but it does the same thing just takes longer.

OK i Apologize i am sending the key command as such

```
SendKeys.Send(""+command+"");
```

the command contains {f7} which is pulled from a database

I Figured out the issue although i had a message box showing the right command there was some other information hidden in there i guess

```
command=command.trim();
SendKeys.Send(""+command+"");
```

Trimming the command first fixed whatever issue there was with it sorry to be a burden on everyone

Comment: Did you try `SendKeys.Send("{F7}");`?

Comment: i Apologize i am Sending it like that i mistyped my example code

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i have edited what i am actually sending aparently if i just send f7 it does work but this command pulling from the database does not

Comment: why the double quotes in Send(""+command+"");?

Comment: @MPatel Send Requires the quotes and calling a string inside it needed quotes around it as well thats the only way it would take the command

Comment: Fair enough if it works for you, however I don't remember doing this when I had used it in the past.

Comment: @MPatel sorry i wish i could tell you why it needs it lol, i Just no it doesn't even allow the program to run without the extra quotes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what needed to be done i needed to trim my command before it was sent 
there apparently was some hidden characters

```
command=command.trim();
SendKeys.Send(""+command+"");
```